# V8 console.log does not print

Tags: javascript, c++, v8, embedded-v8

I am attempting to embed v8 into my application, I am messing about seeing what is included in the V8 environment (duktape does not include a console implementation) and it seems like v8 does include an implementation however when I call `console.log` it does not print anything, instead it just prints undefined (which i assume to be the return value of `console.log`) So how would one go about linking the default `std::cout` output with `console.log`.

This is my code currently, I am working with the default hello world code very slightly modified.

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Initialize V8.
    v8::V8::InitializeICUDefaultLocation(argv[0]);
    v8::V8::InitializeExternalStartupData(argv[0]);
    std::unique_ptr<v8::Platform> platform = v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform();
    v8::V8::InitializePlatform(platform.get());
    v8::V8::Initialize();
    // Create a new Isolate and make it the current one.
    v8::Isolate::CreateParams create_params;
    create_params.array_buffer_allocator =
        v8::ArrayBuffer::Allocator::NewDefaultAllocator();
    v8::Isolate* isolate = v8::Isolate::New(create_params);
    {
        v8::Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate);
        // Create a stack-allocated handle scope.
        v8::HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);
        // Create a new context.
        v8::Local<v8::Context> context = v8::Context::New(isolate);
        // Enter the context for compiling and running the hello world script.
        v8::Context::Scope context_scope(context);
        {
            // Create a string containing the JavaScript source code.
            v8::Local<v8::String> source =
                v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, R"(
                    console.log("does not print?")
                )",
                v8::NewStringType::kNormal)
                .ToLocalChecked();
            // Compile the source code.
            v8::Local<v8::Script> script =
                v8::Script::Compile(context, source).ToLocalChecked();
            // Run the script to get the result.
            v8::Local<v8::Value> result = script->Run(context).ToLocalChecked();
            // Convert the result to an UTF8 string and print it.
            v8::String::Utf8Value utf8(isolate, result);
            printf("%s\n", *utf8);
        }
    }
    // Dispose the isolate and tear down V8.
    isolate->Dispose();
    v8::V8::Dispose();
    v8::V8::ShutdownPlatform();
    delete create_params.array_buffer_allocator;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

and I am using the prebuilt v8 binaries [here](https://github.com/pmed/v8-nuget)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

- `#include "src/debug/interface-types.h"`
- define your own "console delegate" class, deriving from `debug::ConsoleDelegate`
- override any methods you're interested in, e.g. `void Log(const debug::ConsoleCallArguments& args, const v8::debug::ConsoleContext&) override;`
- instantiate it and call `debug::SetConsoleDelegate(isolate, &your_console_delegate);` after creating your `Isolate`

To see an example, start at https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/v8/src/d8/d8-console.h?l=14&gsn=D8Console and trace where it's used.

Comment: I don't seem to have a `src` directory in my includes, my file structure looks like this, I am using the debug configuration in visual studio and in the prebuilt binaries.
```
│   v8-inspector-protocol.h
│   v8-inspector.h
│   v8-internal.h
│   v8-platform.h
│   v8-profiler.h
│   v8-testing.h
│   v8-util.h
│   v8-value-serializer-version.h
│   v8-version-string.h
│   v8-version.h
│   v8-wasm-trap-handler-posix.h
│   v8-wasm-trap-handler-win.h
│   v8.h
│   v8config.h
│
└───libplatform
        libplatform-export.h
        libplatform.h
        v8-tracing.h
```

Comment: Yes, `src` is not inside `include`, it lives next to it. I don't know how your precompiled bundle does things; sounds like you'll have to get the right version of `interface-types.h` yourself. The current version is at https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/refs/heads/master/src/debug/interface-types.h .

Comment: Ok so after a while I did manage to get it to work, it turns out that bundle is incomplete but I was able to Jerryrig it together, Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone in the future that is dealing with this, this is the process I used to fix it.

- download the source from [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/refs/heads/master/src), only the src folder is needed.
- extract it and link it in to your project where ever you put vendor code *in addition to the bundle*.
- put it in the a `src` folder because otherwise its includes don't work
- you will need to make a bunch of include directories for it to compile, mine include `v8/src`, and `v8`
- make sure to link it with the nuget package, you may not have to do this, one machine needed it the other didn't.
- you do not need to generate `builtins-generated/bytecodes-builtins-list.h`